# How do I show a submenu when hovering over a menu item?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have a Drupal 7 site. I need to create menu and sub-menu. I am using the Mega Menu module for this.

This is my menu structure.

[image: My Menu Structure]

Sub-menu not showing up when hovering over a menu item.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that you are simply stating facts, without asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions.

Answer (score 1):

Mega Menu module will create a Block in Blocks section(admin/structure/block).

Enable that block in a particular region and see it in action.

[image]

Comment: enabled in the `header` still not rendering

Comment: 'still not rendering' -> Is that mean entire menu is not rendering or child items are not rendering?

Comment: only child menu is not rendering